# How to edit and create data in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to be able to edit and create new data in a sqlite file using python.

```
def save_updated_data(self, entry_values, update_window, current_row_data):
    updated_row_data = {}
    for entry, (label, value) in zip(entry_values, current_row_data.items()):
        updated_row_data[label] = entry.get() if entry.get() else value

    row_index = self.data.index(current_row_data)
    self.data[row_index] = updated_row_data

    self.save_to_sqlite()
    messagebox.showinfo("Update", "Data updated successfully!")
    update_window.destroy()
    self.display_data()

def create_data_window(self, conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES ({','.join(['?']*len(new_data))})", new_data)
    conn.commit()
    messagebox.showinfo("Create Data", "Data successfully created.")

def save_created_data(self, entry_values, create_window):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES ({','.join(['?']*len(new_data))})", new_data)
    conn.commit()
    messagebox.showinfo("Create Data", "Data successfully created.")

def save_to_sqlite(self, conn, table_name, row_index, column_index, new_value):
    cursor = self.conn.execute('SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" LIMIT 1')
    table_name = cursor.fetchone()[1]
    with self.conn:
        self.conn.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)", (row["column1"], row["column2"]))

        for row in self.data:
            self.conn.execute("INSERT INTO road_data VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)", (row["column1"], row["column2"]))
```

I don't really know why it is not getting saved. It does give me some errors like argument errors. I am only new to coding and I really do enjoy it so far it is just sometimes like these it is difficult. Thank you.

Comment: "It does give me some errors like argument errors" - for a question that involves errors, always include the error and the full stacktrace. Sharing the code is great, but we need to know what problem you're running into. Also, the code you shared are a bunch of functions, but it's unclear where and how you're calling them. For one issue: `save_to_sqlite` doesn't appear to commit.

Comment: We can't possibly help if you do not share the errors...

Comment: You'll have to read and understand the errors and fix the problems before it will work. For example, `save_created_data` is passed `entry_values` and `create_window` but never uses them. It does use `table_name` and `new_data`, but those are not passed in. I'd suggest getting something working without functions first. Also, [never use format strings to add values to SQL statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), instead [pass them into `execute` as parameters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects).

Answer (score 0):

make sure you open and close the connection and cursor correctly, if you're a beginner this is much likely to be a cause. Is your database getting locked? Then you better check how many OPEN cursors you got pointing on your database.

I can't tell you if that's without seeing your errors, but that's what happened to me a lot.

Also your calling:

save_to_sqlite - without any arguments in save_updated_data

save_created_data - without even BEING ABLE to pass the connection

create_data_window - without the necessary 'new_data' and 'table_name'

If you're showing us ALL your code in these functions you probably should learn about global and local variables. This might be your major issue. Not to hard to understand, but critical to know.